# Executing a line in a conditional AND by default on start

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I have this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhaem/Lyzrtefo/7/

```
var orangeMode = true
var isTracking = true

getMouseXY = function(e) {
  if (isTracking) {
  var tempX = e.pageX
  var tempY = e.pageY 

  if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0}
  if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0}  

  document.getElementById("circle1").style.top = (tempY - 25) + "px";
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.left = (tempX - 25) + "px";
  }
  return true
}

document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;

var toggleTrackCircle = function() {
  isTracking = !isTracking;
  console.log(isTracking);
}

document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener("click", toggleTrackCircle);

flip = function() {
  orangeMode = !orangeMode;
  if (orangeMode) { 
  document.getElementById("circle1").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener('mouseover', function() {isTracking = true;})
  // When the above line is executed the circle will stick to your cursor on HOVER after clicking and setting it down.
  } else {
    document.getElementById("circle1").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
}
document.getElementById("box3").addEventListener("click", flip);
```

There is this one line, that when present will change the behavior of the interaction. (You can always click to stop the cursor from tracking you, but when this line is there, the circle will re-stick to it on hover, and when it's not, it will only restick on hover + click.

```
document.getElementById("circle1").addEventListener('mouseover', function() {isTracking = true;})
```

I'm trying to wrap it in some conditional logic in the flip function (which you can control by tapping the red box in the corner) so that orangeMode == it sticks on hover and not orangeMode it only re-sticks on click.

The flip function works fine for changing the color, but this event listener isn't performing like I'd want. (once you cycle through it does work but for either state and it's not running orangeMode unload.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put 'isTracking=true;' inside a named function, so you can use "removeEventListener" to take the function off.  That means you add this function:

```
var trackCircle = function() {
  isTracking = true;
}
```

Then you reference that on click instead of the anonymous function:

```
circle.addEventListener('mouseover', trackCircle)
```

Then you simply remove that event in your else:

```
circle.removeEventListener('mouseover', trackCircle)
```

Oh, and I'd add this at the top so you don't need to keep repeating the getElementById phrase:

```
circle = document.getElementById("circle1");
```

Hope that helps.  Oh, and here's the edit to your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyzrtefo/9/

Comment: You're a hero, sir. <3